# How to add result of lambda function to particular step of step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Here, I have a scenario like in mid of step function, lambda function should add result to that particular step of step function. lambda function will not be take any input from step function. it should be triggered by sns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Your lambda will be outside of the step function. You can have a workaround where you temporarily save resonse of lambda in dynamodb or s3 and then read that table in your step function using another lambda

Comment: Thank you. I found alternate way which is passing required input to lambda by step function.